# Connect to Google Drive via the terminal in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab Pro, and sometimes it disconnects when I am not looking at it for some time. I have ways to save everything to the Google Drive, but it often disconnects from the Drive too, and when both disconnections happen, I lose my data...

With Pro I have access to the terminal, which allows me to do other things while a cell is running. I was wondering if it is possible via commands to connect to Google Drive, so that I do not need to stop my calculations to save my data to the Drive.

Or if there is a way to force reconnection to the Drive once the connection is lost, without stopping the actual cell from running...